# Создаю крестики-нолики. Почему когда условие истина не выполняется данный код?

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

Не выполняется код над этим условием: `if(example % 2 == 0)`.

```js
var check=$("#timer").html();
var example=check;


if(example % 2 == 0 )
    {
        $('#second').click(function() {
        $(this).css('background-image', 'url(X.png)');
        
        example++;
        $("#timer").html(example);
        
        });
    }
   else
   {
       $('#first').click(function() {
       $(this).css('background-image', 'url(Zero.png)');
        
           example++;
        $("#timer").html(example);
       
        
       
       });
   }
```

```css
.general
{
    border: 1px solid #000000;
    width: 150px;
    height: 150px;
    background-color: #05EFFF;
    
}

table
{
  
   margin: 0 auto;
   margin-top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html> 
<html> 
<head> 
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css"> 
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html charsеt=utf-8"> 
<title>TIC-TAC-TOE</title> 
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js" ></script>
</head> 
<body> 
 
   
<table>
    <tr>
        <td><div id="first" class="general"></div></td><td><div  id="second" class="general"></div></td><td><div id="third"class="general" ></div></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><div id="fourth" class="general" ></div></td><td><div id="fiveth" class="general" ></div></td><td><div id="sixth" class="general" ></div></td>
    </tr>
    
    <tr>
        <td><div id="seventh" class="general" ></div></td><td><div id="eightth" class="general" ></div></td><td><div id="nineth" class="general" ></div></td>
    </tr>
</table>
    <p id="timer" >1</p>

    
    <script type="text/javascript" src="js.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: `$("#timer").html();` получает строку.......вам нужно целое число......тобишь использовать `parseInt` https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/parseInt

Comment: Не меняет ситуацию.

Comment: как вы определяете, что не меняет ситуацию? я число 2 и норм.... я вот в отладчике смотрю, а вы?

Comment: Пишу в коде, а потом запускаю в браузере.

Comment: и проверяю.....

Comment: А мне нужно не число, у меня это работает. У меня не работает условие  if(example % 2 == 0 ) , которое должно выполнять участок кода ниже

Comment: А он выполняется вполне себе..... https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNUJ1.jpg ..... разве что вы просто не так обработчик навешиваете и нужен не `click`, а `on` и вы имеете в виду, что у вас именно клик не работает....... а вот условие вполне себе работает

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$(".general").click(function() {
  if (example % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    example++;
    $("#timer").html(example);
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');

    example++;
    $("#timer").html(example);
  }
})
```

```js
var check = $("#timer").html();
var example = check;
$(".general").click(function() {
  if (example % 2 == 0) {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'red');
    example++;
    $("#timer").html(example);
  } else {
    $(this).css('background-color', 'yellow');

    example++;
    $("#timer").html(example);
  }
})
```

```css
.general {
  border: 1px solid #000000;
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  background-color: #05EFFF;
}
table {
  margin: 0 auto;
  margin-top: 15%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="first" class="general"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="second" class="general"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="third" class="general"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="fourth" class="general"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="fiveth" class="general"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="sixth" class="general"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>
      <div id="seventh" class="general"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="eightth" class="general"></div>
    </td>
    <td>
      <div id="nineth" class="general"></div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
<p id="timer">2</p>
```